# IMEI null/null?

Tags: dialer-codes

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9305T, and I am getting a "Insert SIM card to access network services" error. I dialled *#06# and it said null/null, meaning I have a null IMEI. How do I fix this? Is it fixable?

Comment: Not all phones use the same dialing codes... You should update your question with your make and model of device, Android version, how you happened to lose your IMEI number, link to your "tutorial", and any other information you think is relevant (do NOT include IMEI numbers) otherwise your question will likely be flagged for closure as too vague/broad.

Comment: Also be aware that most modern devices cannot have the IMEI number modified through a simple service menu, some cannot have it modified by the user at all and if it gets "lost" it is a brick condition. Not trying to scare you but there are lots of old tutorials out there that just do not apply to modern devices.

Comment: @acejavelin I updated the question.

Comment: I second @acejavelin. Not all phones respond to secret codes uniformly. Indigo this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) and check for IMEI number. You can verify number displayed against the number on the box (if you have it) or against sales receipt ( if it had that)